# Windows 10 Freezes while asleep

Tags: laptop, windows-10, freeze, sleep, hibernate

My model laptop is a Toshiba Satellite L505D-S5983 with Windows 10. I have to hard reboot sometimes 2-3 times per day.

I put it in hibernate when I need to walk away and when I return it will not wake up. When this happens the fan is running and all the lights on the front are on.

I have to hold down the start button to power down and then power it on again and it works fine. This only happens while it's asleep.

Answer (score 0):

> **Windows 10 Freezes while asleep**
>
> I put it in hibernate when I need to walk away and when I return it
>   will not wake up.

Below are a few things to check and set accordingly to potentially help resolve this issue.

### Power Options

1. Press the <kbd>**Windows Key**</kbd>**+**<kbd>**R**</kbd>
2. Type in **`%windir%\system32\control.exe /name Microsoft.PowerOptions`**
   and press <kbd>**Enter**</kbd>
3. Select the **`Choose what the power button does`** option and set all available options with the values just as shown in the below screen shot and then press <kbd>**Save Changes**</kbd>.
   [image]
4. Now in the **`Choose or customize a power plan`** section, select the **`Change plan settings`** option for which ever of the options that has the bullet point marked filled in or checked on the computer (likely either **Balanced** or **Power saver** *(see below screen shot)*).

   [image]

In the new Window select the **`Change advanced power settings`**.

Scroll down to the **`Power buttons and lid`** section and set all the below options as specified below:

(Set both **`Lid close actions`** as **`Sleep`**)

[image]

(Set both **`Power button actions`** as **`Hibernate`**)

[image]

(Set both **`Sleep button action`** as **`Turn off the display`**, if available, or **`Sleep`** otherwise)

[image]

Scroll up to the **`Hard Disk`** section and set all the below options as specified below:

(Set both **`Turn off hard disk after`** option as the **`180 minutes`** value)

[image]

Press <kbd>**Apply**</kbd> and then <kbd>**OK**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and traced it to having two active antivirus programs which conflicted with each other.

Comment: Explaining how you tracked this, and if possible, what programs were that cause, would make this an answer. Right now it is just a comment.